# Purchased video on iTunes rather than gifting, can this be corrected?

Tags: itunes-store

My friend tried to gift me a film in the iTunes store but he says that somehow he "received" it by mistake (his mistake, most likely).

What are his options now.  Can he:

1. Return the purchase
2. "Gift" the purchase to me
3. Call someone to correct the error and reassign the item to me instead?

Answer (score 2):

bckbck is correct in terms of the letter of the law. All sales are final. However, your friend *may* have some luck contacting iTunes customer service and explaining the situation. They're aware that mistakes happen, and are sometimes happy to rectify them for you - though they are not obliged to do so.

All iTunes customer service is carried out via email. [Here's a link](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact.html?form=cards_codes&topic=iTunes%20Cards%20and%20Codes&subtopic=iTunes%20Gift%20Options) to an email page your friend can use to explain the issue to iTunes customer service.

Comment: No problem. If my answer (or another answer) solved your problem you can mark it "accepted" by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

No.

From the [iTunes Store Terms and Conditions](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html):

> All sales and rentals of products are final.